# nbitcoin управление кошельком

Tags: c#, bitcoin, nbitcoin

Стоит задача : управлять биткоин кошельком программно, средствами c#. Долго гуглив, наткнулся на библиотеку `NBitcoin`, на сколько я понял, мы передаем `private key` в результате можем узнать адрес для принятия денег.

```
var bitcoinPrivateKey = new BitcoinSecret("xxxxxx");
var network = bitcoinPrivateKey.Network;
var address = bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress();
```

У меня 2 вопроса :

1. Правильно ли я генерирую новый приват ключ(что бы потом получить новый адрес) :

`Console.WriteLine( new Key().GetWif(network));`

2. Что я не так делаю при отправке бтц ? пример отправки :

[взял отсюда](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/835098/NBitcoin-Build-Them-All#simple)

```
Transaction aliceFunding = new Transaction()
        {
            Outputs =
            {
    new TxOut("0.45", bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress()),
    new TxOut("0.8", bitcoinPrivateKey.PubKey)
            }
        };

        Coin[] aliceCoins = aliceFunding
                                .Outputs
                                .Select((o, i) => new Coin(new OutPoint(aliceFunding.GetHash(), i), o))
                                .ToArray();

        var txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder();
        var tx = txBuilder
            .AddCoins(aliceCoins)
            .AddKeys(bitcoinPrivateKey.PrivateKey)
            .Send(new BitcoinPubKeyAddress("12.....G"), "0.00090")
            .SendFees("0.0000113")
            .SetChange(bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress())
            .BuildTransaction(true);
```

Никакой ошибки нет, но бтц не отправились

Дополнение :
узнал, что нужно "зарегистрировать" транзакцию в системе, попытался так :

```
 using (var node = Node.Connect(Network.Main, "89.85.201.236:8333"))
        {
            node.VersionHandshake();

            node.SendMessage(new InvPayload(InventoryType.MSG_TX, tx.GetHash()));

            node.SendMessage(new TxPayload(tx));
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
```

Сам адрес `89.85.201.236:8333` взял отсюда [bitnodes.earn.com](https://bitnodes.earn.com/) , но никаких изменений нет (( адрес проверил на том же сайте, вродь валидный

Правка для ответа 1 :

```
 Transaction aliceFunding = new Transaction();
            var input = new TxIn();
            input.PrevOut = new OutPoint(aliceFunding.GetHash(), 0);
            input.ScriptSig = bitcoinPrivateKey.ScriptPubKey;
            aliceFunding.AddInput(input);

            var output = new TxOut();
            var dest = BitcoinAddress.Create("12....G");
            Money free = Money.Satoshis(10);
            output.Value = Money.Coins(0.0009388m) - free; //у меня всего на счету 0.0009388 btc
            output.ScriptPubKey = dest.ScriptPubKey;
            aliceFunding.AddOutput(output);

            aliceFunding.Sign(bitcoinPrivateKey,false);

         //пытался и так

            //var txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder();
            //var tx = txBuilder
            //    .AddCoins(aliceFunding)
            //    .AddKeys(bitcoinPrivateKey.PrivateKey)
            //    .Send(new BitcoinPubKeyAddress("12G", Network.Main), "0.00070")
            //    .SendFees(free)
            //    .SetChange(bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress())
            //    .BuildTransaction(true);

            using (var node = Node.Connect(Network.Main, "13.58.209.229:8333"))
            {
                node.VersionHandshake();

                node.SendMessage(new InvPayload(aliceFunding));

                node.SendMessage(new TxPayload(aliceFunding));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
```

Comment: Что значит бтц не отправились? Вы попробовали запустить транзакцию в реальную сеть?

Comment: @Zergatul дополнил вопрос, у меня нет локального кошелька биткойна, по этому воспользовался сторонним адресом, можете тыкнуть носом, что я не так сделал ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Это будет приватный ключ в формате WIF (Wallet Import Format).
2. Я в самой библиотеке `nbitcoin` не разбирался, но вижу в коде несколько проблем.

`Transaction aliceFunding =`

Здесь должна быть реальная транзакция. А вы генерируете что-то в памяти, что не имеет отношения к реальному блокчейну. Для того, что бы потратить средства, одного приватного ключа недостаточно, вам нужны еще и айди реальных транзакций, выходы которых вы собираетесь использовать.

```
.Send(new BitcoinPubKeyAddress("12.....G"), "0.00090")
.SendFees("0.0000113")
```

Выше в вас `0.45 + 0.8` биткоина, вы отправляете `0.00090` с комиссией `0.0000113`. Сеть биткоин устроена так, что все монеты с выходов транзакций должны быть потрачены, нельзя потратить только часть.

Вашу транзакцию не зарегистрируют, потому что она невалидная.

Comment: а можно по подробнее про `Transaction-ID` ? откуда именно его брать ? т.е `aliceFunding` у меня должна быть вся сумма, что есть на кошельке ?

Comment: В вас есть транзакция А, которая переводит на адрес Х 0.1 биткоин. В вас есть приватный ключ от адреса Х. Что-бы потратить средства, вы создаёте транзакцию Б, которая ссылается на транзакцию А при помощи айди. Так как транзакция А могла переводить биткоины на адрес Y, вам так же нужно знать индекс выхода, который переводил на адрес Х. В вашем коде выше это i: new Output(hash, i)

Comment: GetHash() это и есть айди транзакции, если подставите правильную транзакцию, библиотека сама посчитает айди

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил код, проверьте пожалуйста, никаких ошибок не выходит, но бтц не отправились, я, вроде бы, сделал, как вы сказали. Немног код отформатировал

Comment: `input.PrevOut = new OutPoint(aliceFunding.GetHash(), 0);` это безсмысленно, транзакция не может ссылаться сама на себя. Посмотрите лучше в блокчейне айди транзакции, и пропишите ее в коде напрямую.

Comment: спасибо, не подскажите : допустим, я принял несколько транз на разные адреса своего кошелька (менял приват ключ), что бы посчитать всю сумму, что у меня есть, мне надо  пройтись по каждому адресу и все сложить ? и еще одно достаточно ли будет одного приват ключа, что бы сгенерировать новый адрес ? или Mnemonic слова тож нужны ?

Comment: Да, берете сумму. Я не сильно разбираюсь в генерациях ключей, не могу подсказать

Comment: спасибо, подскажите еще с одним вопросом )) есть ли возможность узнать заранее, какой сейчас адрес используется ? т.е, мне нужно посчитать сумму, но я не знаю сколько всего было сгенерировано адресов, мне на ум приходит только такой вариант : сделать цикл while, где будет генерироваться адрес и проверять баланс, работает до тех пор, пока не получит адрес, где не было операций. Мб есть способ по легче ?

Comment: Не знаю, плохо представляю что вы имеете ввиду. Задайте лучше отдельный вопрос